# Android FrameLayout.addView(camera_view) crashes app

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I'm creating a app which has a camera built by myself using camera preview. And it works fine on my `Android 4.1` device (the camera opens and takes photos). But when I try on my Android 2.3 device, the app crashes on `framelayout.addView(camera_view)` because when I comment this line the app doesn't crashes.
Here's my code (the measures are just to fit the device screen):

```
private void setUpCamera() {

    camera_view = new CameraSurfaceView(getApplicationContext());

    frame_layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_frame);

    // v it's a square that I draw
    v.getLayoutParams().width = (int) ((720/4) + (5*screenDensity));
    v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) ((720/4) + (5*screenDensity));

    // img it's the imageview where I display the photo
    img.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (720/4);
    img.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (720/4);

    frame_layout.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (720/4);
    frame_layout.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (960/4);

    frame_layout.addView(camera_view);

}
```

Here is the camera_view class:

```
public class CameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder m_holder;
    public Camera camera = null;

    public CameraSurfaceView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        m_holder = getHolder();
        m_holder.addCallback(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } else {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
        }

        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
        params.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
        params.setExposureCompensation(0);
        params.setJpegQuality(100);

        List<Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
        for(int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++)
        {
            if(sizes.get(i).width > size.width)
               size = sizes.get(i);
        }

        params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
        params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);

        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        camera = Camera.open();

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(m_holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;

    }

    public void capture(Camera.PictureCallback jpeghandler){

        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpeghandler);

    }

}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: It doesn't appear nothing and the device is on debug mode, which is weird. Could it be a device problem(it's a cheap phone)?

Comment: If your app is crashing, you are supposed to get a stack trace in LogCat. The exception is if you are debugging your app in Eclipse, in which case Eclipse will report the exception first. Run your app outside of the Eclipse debugger (i.e., "Run" instead of "Debug"), and you should see the crash information in LogCat. If you don't, there is little anyone will be able to do to help you.

Comment: Post code for camera_view along with the crash logcat or simply backport your camera_view to Android2.1

Comment: No, the logcat it's not working at all. It's a Huawei. Is there problems like this one with this device brand? Cause with the other device that I have, it shows me every thing on logcat. It this one, nothing.